# Bulk reduce image size with Paint.net

Tags: paint.net

Is there a way to reduce the image size for all the images you have open in Paint.Net in one set of actions or do you have to do each image one by one?

Comment: If its just resizing other tools may be faster - i'm rather fond of the image resize powertoys, which add a context menu option to resize

Comment: This is a bulk resizing tool that is quick and easy to use: 
https://www.faststone.org/FSResizerDetail.htm
  I know this is old thread, but it came up near top of list when I searched for "paint.net bulk resize" so thought I would add my solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try "[Paint.NET Bulk Image Processor](http://pdnbulkupdater.codeplex.com/)":

> PDNBulkUpdater is a plug-in for Paint.NET that allows you to
>   efficiently perform operations such as resizing and converting
>   multiple images at the same time. The plug-in contains both an
>   integrated UI and a command line tool.

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin doesn't work with paint.net 4, yet.

Comment: I'm in the process of updating it to work with the latest Paint.NET (4.0.3)

Comment: In the meantime: Directory Opus has a Convert image... feature that works even for collections of images.

Comment: Not yet updated to 4.0.10 :(

Answer (score 2):

There's a fork of "Paint.NET Bulk Image Processor" for Paint.NET 4

[Bulk Actions plugin for Paint.NET](https://github.com/stephensmitchell-forks/bulk-actions-for-paint-dot-net)

Comment: How does itanswer the question?

Comment: Previous answer doesn't work anymore for the latest Paint.Net, and I can't comment on previous answer, so I posted a new answer, "because Bulk Actions plugin for Paint.NET" is exactly what you need to "Bulk reduce image size with Paint.net", which is the question.

Comment: link now broken

Comment: https://github.com/stephensmitchell-forks/bulk-actions-for-paint-dot-net

Comment: Sadly there are no releases so you'd have to compile it yourself, and now there's Paint.NET 5 too